# $\int\frac{x }{ \sqrt {3-x^4}}{dx} $ by substitution method

Tags: integration

I am trying to determine via substitution:

$$\int\frac{x }{ \sqrt {3-x^4}}{dx} $$

My work:

$$x=\frac{1}{t}$$
$$dx=-\frac{dt}{t^2}$$
$$ - \int\frac{dt }{ t \sqrt {3t^4-1}} $$

How to proceed further ?

Comment: Start again, let $x^2=\sqrt{3}\,u$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas How you interpreted this ? It is easy this way .

Comment: It's kinda standard to do a substitution of that kind when you have $x^4$ in the denominator and $x$ in the numerator..

Comment: Well, maybe I should have done it in two steps. Because $x$ is almost the derivative of $x^2$, it is natural to let $x^2=t$. We end up integrating $(1/2)\frac{1}{\sqrt{3-t^2}}$. Now there is a natural further substitution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The single substitution $$x^4 = 3 \sin^2 \theta, \quad 2x \, dx = \sqrt{3} \cos \theta \, d\theta$$ immediately yields $$\int \frac{x \, dx}{\sqrt{3-x^4}} = \frac{1}{2} \int \frac{\sqrt{3} \cos \theta \, d\theta}{\sqrt{3}\sqrt{1-\sin^2 \theta}} = \frac{\theta}{2} + C = \frac{1}{2} \sin^{-1} \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{3}} + C.$$